# Property does not exist on the type of object error after subscribe in angular 5? Check below code in screenshot

Tags: angular

I am trying to fetch data from API. If you check [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn7DK.png), data is fetched but when I want to fetch object it shows error. I am using Angular 6 and subscribe method.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please, visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Show us your code, error messages you are getting, anything that could help others to help you.

Comment: Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked accessing the object property directly or doing any operation on it like just try console.log first item of your articles array. The error you see might be just an editor warning(happens if the editor still indexing the data). If it's not the case can you provide more details?